# How to select colors to plot different categories in R?

Tags: r, plot

I was searching to find set of colors that can be matched to differentiate between 7-9 categories. Do you have any idea if there is a website to give suggestions about selecting colors ?

Answer (score 2):

This website http://colorbrewer2.org/ is a very good to suggest some colors in HEX format based on your type of data (i.e sequential, diverging,..), so you can use it in your R code. For example,

```
colors <- c("#d73027","#fc8d59","#fee090","#ffffbf","#e0f3f8","#91bfdb","#4575b4")
# then use this vector in your col attribute in your barplot for example.
```

Comment: and note the `RColorBrewer` package which makes it easier to use (but the website is also definitely worth exploring).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some R functions for this, like `rainbow()` and `heat.colors()`.

```
plot(1:7, col = rainbow(7))
```

Comment: But these colors when you have many categories, it will be annoying. You can test the difference between this website and using rainbow for large number of colors.

Answer (score 1):

The colorspace package has functions that will help in choosing color palettes and has a nice vignette describing how to use the package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html).  It even has an interactive tool that you can use to set aspects of the palette and see immediately the colors involved, it even allows you to see what the colors will look like to someone who is color blind or what will happen if your plot is printed/copied in greyscale.